# Get the youtube playlist detail using the v3 API

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID
```

This will get the list data of a youtube channel , for example

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/UUY8zZ2vTM_ipmlSwy7CPFpw?v=3&alt=json
```

This, will get the data in JSON format. however, since the API has switched to V3  I wonder are there a URL that does the same thing?

Tried something like

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet
                        &channelId=UUY8zZ2vTM_ipmlSwy7CPFpw
```

but no luck. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between Channel & Playlist.
Check out this page for more information. https://code.google.com/apis/console/
There you need to go to "YouTube Data API v3 > youtube.channels.list" which will allow you to test the action you want to perform.